# Bootstrap 4 navbar - collapse on nav-link click in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the Bootstrap 4 navbar only use vanilla js vs any jQuery. So far I've been able to get the toggler to trigger the nav to collapse and close on mobile. What I am now trying to figure out is how to make the navbar collapse when you click on a "nav-link"

Here is my HTML for the nav:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#visit">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my JS for the collapsing

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    document.querySelectorAll("button.navbar-toggler")[0].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      var target = this.getAttribute("data-target");
      var subbar = document.querySelectorAll(target)[0];
      subbar.className = (subbar.className + " show").replace(/ show show/, "");
    });
  })();
```

But how do I make it so when a user clicks a `<a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>` it'll also collapse the navbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using custom code, it's unnecessary to have the target (`data-target="#navbarResponsive"`) on the html. So we can rewrite the `click` handler to handle both elements, the toggler and the links. To toggle a class just use the method `toggle` on `classList`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("navbar-toggler-icon")) {
    document.getElementById("navbarResponsive").classList.toggle("show");
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("nav-link")) {
    document.getElementById("navbarResponsive").classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse Menu</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#visit">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this snipped didn't work for me but I still appreciate it!

Comment: Fixed now. Should be `navbar-toggler-icon` instead of `navbar-toggler`

Comment: Quick follow up question: How do I make the nav collapse again if someone clicks the toggler for a second time?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your question is to find all the `.nav-link`s and add a click listener to remove the `show` class from the class list.

Also, you could simplify a bit your code using [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), something like:

```js
(function() {
  let subbar = document.getElementById("navbarResponsive");
  document
    .querySelectorAll("button.navbar-toggler")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      subbar.classList.toggle("show");
    });
  for (let navItem of document.querySelectorAll("a.nav-link")) {
    navItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      subbar.classList.remove("show");
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#visit">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```